# Disable keyboard Keys in WYSIHTML5

Tags: javascript, richtextbox, rich-text-editor, onkeydown, wysihtml5

I want to disable all keyboard keys in wysihtml5 text editor .
I am using this editor https://github.com/bassjobsen/wysihtml5-image-upload
can anyone help me to do this.
 I have try "load" event and its works perfectly but i cannot use "onkeypress" or "onkeyup"\

```
var defaultOptions = $.fn.wysihtml5.defaultOptions = {
"font-styles": false,
    "color": false,
    "emphasis": false,
    "lists": false,
    "html": false,
    "link": false,
    "image": true,
    events: {
        "load": function() {
            console.log('loaded!');
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is the answer below

```
var defaultOptions = $.fn.wysihtml5.defaultOptions = {
    "font-styles": false,
    "color": false,
    "emphasis": false,
    "lists": false,
    "html": false,
    "link": false,
    "image": true,
    events: {
        "load": function() {
            $('.wysihtml5-sandbox').contents().find('body').on("keydown",function(event) {
                return false;
            });
        }
    },
```